# Is it possible to permanently miss items?

Tags: bastion

In Bastion, some levels have items lying on the ground. Some of them merely provide NPC dialog, others are weapon upgrade materials, all of them give a small XP bonus.

The levels I've already cleared are marked with a red star on the map, and I can't revisit them.

If I clear a level without picking up all the items, are they lost forever, or would I be able to replay the level in this case? Can I miss out on weapon upgrades by not being thorough enough?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

All items that you miss turn up in the Lost and Found item shop. The only penalty for missing them is that you have to buy them instead of getting them for free.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. All the items, or just the weapon upgrades? Because I've definitely seen upgrade materials in there, but not conversation pieces.

Comment: @lunboks I'm pretty sure that mementos also go there, but I don't have proof, I'll need to do some testing.

Answer (score 2):

Not really, having a New Game+ save you from loosing any important item. If you don't get it the first time you can always get it in a new round.